# How to optimize my app to lower the battery usage?

Tags: android

I am making an android app which uses GPS tracking system, but it uses lot of battery, How to optimize my app to lower the battery usage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on your scenario.

You need to think about "reducing" the GPS usage in your app as much as possible, in proportion to your functionality.

For instance, if your application only need to send a tracking "dots" of the device to the server - you can turn the GPS, take a current location "snapshot an" then turn the GPS off or suspend it etc...

There is no generic solution for your question, you need to do a little thinking here :).

Comment: Thanks a lot I am done with taht issue,now the new issue i am facing is that my marker is dragged fine but I want a constant motion of the marker as the device moves but instead of that it keeps on updating its position

Comment: Yeah, I think you got two choices here (if you want to keep the battery usage low) you can leave the view updates as is, or you can calculate "potential" movement of the marker and draw it between the "snapshots" deltas. So the user will get a smooth animation experience, but the motion will be faked...

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the time after which location is refreshed. Please see following to constants in given class.

**MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES and 
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location networklocation; // location
    Location gpslocation; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    float accuracy;
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    private static final float HOW_ACCURATE = 50;
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;        
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        float currentAccuracy = HOW_ACCURATE + 1;
        int returnWhat = 0;

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        networklocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (networklocation != null) {
                            this.latitude = networklocation.getLatitude();
                            this.longitude = networklocation.getLongitude();
                            currentAccuracy = networklocation.getAccuracy();
                            returnWhat = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (networklocation == null
                            || currentAccuracy > HOW_ACCURATE) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            gpslocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (gpslocation != null) {      
                                //Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS Accuracy: "+gpslocation.getAccuracy()+", Current Accuracy: "+currentAccuracy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if (gpslocation.getAccuracy() < currentAccuracy) {
                                    this.latitude = gpslocation.getLatitude();
                                    this.longitude = gpslocation.getLongitude();
                                    returnWhat = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (returnWhat == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Getting location from Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            gpslocation = null;
            this.accuracy = networklocation.getAccuracy();
            return networklocation;
        } else if (returnWhat == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Getting location from GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            networklocation = null;
            this.accuracy = gpslocation.getAccuracy();
            return gpslocation;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public float getLocAccuracy() {
        return this.accuracy;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {               
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```